# Can I run multiple sections of SQL in one statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I have several SQL statements for test data. There's a bunch of insert statements, a bunch of select statements, and a bunch of delete statements.

Is it possible to have these insert statements wrapped in something that I can run from one line of code? Then, with one statement, I could say, execute the inserts. Or, execute the delete statements.

Here's an example of what I have

```
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);
```

Here's what I imagine it would look like, but since I don't know if it's even possible, this may look silly.

`execute sqlChunk();`
Which would run everything below.

```
sqlChunk(){   
  insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
  insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
  insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
  insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
  insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
}
```

Note that I just put the statements in brackets, because to me, it'd be something like this (again if it's possible). I am running this in DB2. But would also like to know if you could do it in oracle sql.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a store procedure a function or a job to encapsulate your query, where sqlChunk would be like.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sqlChuck
AS
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);
insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);
```

and you'd call it like:

```
EXEC sqlChuck
```

And as far as I can tell, it can also be done in oracle.

Comment: This is what I want to do. So at the top of my sql document I want to have  `EXEC deleteTestData;`   
`EXEC insertTestData;`  
`EXEC showTestData;`  
How does the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement know when to end? I have 3 in one document.

Comment: You simply type the script to create your procedure, run it and then close it, the procedure will be saved and you'll be able to use/call it anytime you want.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm using SQLDeveloper, and .sql worksheets. I guess what you are suggesting would work more in command line?

Comment: @EmmanuelRC Don't you need to put your `INSERT` statements inside a `BEGIN` ... `END` block?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle supports a multi-table syntax for insertions, INSERT ALL.  It looks something like this

```
  insert all
     into table2 values (val1, val2, val3) 
     into table3 values (val1, val3)  
     into table4 values (val1, val4, val5)  
     into table5 values (val1, val2, val4)  
     into table6 values (val1, val2, val2)
  select * from table1;
```

Note that it only works as INSERT ... SELECT; we cannot use VALUES as the source.  (Although we can select literals from DUAL. )  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#i2095116).

As far as I know DB2 does not have a similar syntax.

---

Of course, both Oracle and [DB2 support stored procedures](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/c0007033.htm).  A stored procedure is just a way of group of multiple SQL statements so they can be executed with a single call.

Answer (score 1):

Both Oracle database and DB2 support anonymous SQL blocks, like this:

```
begin 
 insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
 insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
 insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
 insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
 insert into [table] values (val1, val2, val3);  
end
```

In DB2 this is also called *compound SQL*. From the application program point of view the block is a single SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

With oracle you can do this:

```
insert into mytable
(field1, field2, field3)
select value1, value2, value3
from dual
union
select value4, value5, value6
from dual
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using DB2 for i, you can insert multiple rows like this:

```
insert into mytable
  values (value1, value2, value3),
         (value1, value2, value3),
         (value1, value2, value3),
         (value1, value2, value3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy it all to a file. Call it as you want. and run as a script from SQL*PLUS.

Example in windows:

```
c:\>sqlplus user/password@database_name @c:\script_name.sql
```

or

```
c:\>sqlplus user/password@database_name
SQL>@script_name.sql
```

or

```
c:\>sqlplus user/password@database_name
SQL>@@all_scripts.sql
```

The @@all_scripts.sql file can contain more than one file:

```
@script1.sql
@script2.sql
@script3.sql
```